# Same Strings when compared returns false

Tags: java

Could somebody please help me why comparing these two String returns false
Here is the code:

```
<%@ page language="java" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%        
    response.setHeader("Pragma", "No-cache");
    response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate");
    response.setDateHeader("Expires", -1);
%>

<jsp:useBean id="user" class="beans.ConnectToDB" scope="session" />
<jsp:useBean id="aes" class="beans.AES" scope="session" />

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache" />
        <meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache" />
        <meta http-equiv="Expires" content="Sat, 01 Dec 2001 00:00:00 GMT" />
        <title>Authenticating - Checking Credentials</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <%
            String getUsername = request.getParameter("username");
            String getPassword = request.getParameter("password");  

            final String passphrase = "#asdf@1234#";    
            byte[] password_byte = getPassword.getBytes();  
            byte[] passphrase_byte = passphrase.getBytes();
            byte[] encrypt_password = aes.encrypt(password_byte, passphrase_byte);
            String encrypt_password_str = new String(encrypt_password);     

            if((getUsername != null && !getUsername.isEmpty()) || (getPassword != null && !getPassword.isEmpty())){
                String username_from_db = user.getUsername(getUsername);
                String password_from_db = user.getPassword(getUsername);

                if(getUsername.equalsIgnoreCase(username_from_db) && encrypt_password_str.equals(password_from_db)){
                    response.sendRedirect("client/home_page.jsp");
                }
                else{ 
                    out.println("Original Encrypted Password: " + encrypt_password_str + "<br />");                 
                    out.println("Encrypted Password from D: " + password_from_db);
                }   
            }
            else{ response.sendRedirect("index.jsp"); }
        %>
    </body>
</html>
```

And here is the result:

```
Original Encrypted Password: I[?y?Ì®õ¹A,®}
Encrypted Password from D: I[?y?Ì®õ¹A,®}
```

If I am correct, it is the same string.

Comment: What if getUsername.equalsIgnoreCase(username_from_db) was wrong ?

Comment: You should not compare encrypted passwords on Java side because it means that in every case, the true encrypted password exists in the JVM and is potentially visible. Prefer "SELECT [...] FROM ... WHERE LOGIN=... AND ENCRYPTED_PASSWORD=..." : if it does not return anything, refuse authentication.

Comment: I didn't get exactly what you mean:) sorry it is really my first time in jsp and javabeans,

Answer (score 0):

Usernames don't seem to be the same. Print them to be sure (you just print passwords).

In an `if` where 2 conditions are joined with a logical `AND`, you are sure that the 2nd one is `true` and the `if` returns `false`, then the first condition must be `false`.